# SET NOCOUNT ON using ADO is not supressing PRINT messages

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, vbscript, ado, adodb

In my application I am using the following code:

```
Set oRs = oConn.Execute("SET NOCOUNT ON; EXECUTE mySp;")
```

`mySp` returns `PRINT` messages and my application is returning them as errors.

How do I make it so the `PRINT` messages don't show up so it won't trigger an error in my application?

I tried to set `SET NOCOUNT ON;` but that doesn't seem to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SET NOCOUNT ON` suppresses the `(n) row(s) affected` message.

To stop the print statements from executing inside your procedure,  you would need to remove them print statements from the procedure definition.

Comment: Thanks for your response. In Asp.Net it doesn't print these messages, this only happens in classic asp VBScript using ADO.  Not sure as to why though.

Comment: yes because ado.not doesnt know what to do with these "unexpected" result sets begin returned by the query.

Comment: Actually, I figured it out. I just use the same string that my ASP.Net app does.  See my answer

Answer (score 0):

For those of you looking how to solve this, I simply added  `MultipleActiveResultSets=True;` to my connection string and it started working how it should. Bypassing all the `PRINT` messages.